# Place order, clear Cart in Nop Commerce 4

Tags: shopping-cart, nopcommerce

How can I Place an order from the cart and clear the cart?
I want to do this in my own controller and not by the checkout page.

I try to use this, but it doesn't work

```
//place order
var processPaymentRequest = HttpContext.Session.Get<ProcessPaymentRequest>("OrderPaymentInfo");

if (processPaymentRequest == null)
{
    //Check whether payment workflow is required
    if (_orderProcessingService.IsPaymentWorkflowRequired(cart))
        return RedirectToRoute("CheckoutPaymentInfo");

    processPaymentRequest = new ProcessPaymentRequest();
}
GenerateOrderGuid(processPaymentRequest);
processPaymentRequest.StoreId = _storeContext.CurrentStore.Id;
processPaymentRequest.CustomerId = _workContext.CurrentCustomer.Id;
processPaymentRequest.PaymentMethodSystemName = 
_genericAttributeService.GetAttribute<string>(_workContext.CurrentCustomer,
NopCustomerDefaults.SelectedPaymentMethodAttribute, 
_storeContext.CurrentStore.Id);
HttpContext.Session.Set<ProcessPaymentRequest>("OrderPaymentInfo", 
                 processPaymentRequest);
                var placeOrderResult = _orderProcessingService.PlaceOrder(processPaymentRequest);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `PlaceOrder` method in `IOrderProcessingService` to place an order. `CheckoutController` also uses this method. For using it, you have to create a `ProcessPaymentRequest` by yourself. here is a sample code for such a task (I use the code placed in the `CheckoutController` which doing the same job):

```
var processPaymentRequest = HttpContext.Session.Get<ProcessPaymentRequest>("OrderPaymentInfo");
if (processPaymentRequest == null)
{
    //Check whether payment workflow is required
    if (_orderProcessingService.IsPaymentWorkflowRequired(cart))
        return RedirectToRoute("CheckoutPaymentInfo");

    processPaymentRequest = new ProcessPaymentRequest();
}

//prevent 2 orders being placed within an X seconds time frame
if (!IsMinimumOrderPlacementIntervalValid(_workContext.CurrentCustomer))
    throw new Exception(_localizationService.GetResource("Checkout.MinOrderPlacementInterval"));

//place order
processPaymentRequest.StoreId = _storeContext.CurrentStore.Id;
processPaymentRequest.CustomerId = _workContext.CurrentCustomer.Id;
processPaymentRequest.PaymentMethodSystemName = _workContext.CurrentCustomer.GetAttribute<string>(
SystemCustomerAttributeNames.SelectedPaymentMethod,
_genericAttributeService, _storeContext.CurrentStore.Id);
//____this is main line of code____
var placeOrderResult = _orderProcessingService.PlaceOrder(processPaymentRequest);
if (placeOrderResult.Success)
{
    HttpContext.Session.Set<ProcessPaymentRequest>("OrderPaymentInfo", null);
    //do payment process:
    var postProcessPaymentRequest = new PostProcessPaymentRequest
    {
        Order = placeOrderResult.PlacedOrder
    };
    _paymentService.PostProcessPayment(postProcessPaymentRequest);

    if (_webHelper.IsRequestBeingRedirected || _webHelper.IsPostBeingDone)
    {
        //redirection or POST has been done in PostProcessPayment
        return Content("Redirected");
    }

    return RedirectToRoute("CheckoutCompleted", new { orderId = placeOrderResult.PlacedOrder.Id });
}
```